# Is it possible to configure Windows "resource exhaustion detector" to detect and log high cpu events, rather than just low memory events?

Tags: windows, cpu-usage

Is it possible to configure Windows "resource exhaustion detector" feature to detect and log **high cpu events**, rather than just **low memory events**?

As some may know, if Windows detects a low memory condition, the "resource exhaustion detector" mechanism will detect that and report it in the Windows Event Logs (System), as eventid 2004, and with a source of "resource-exhaustion-detector".

Sadly, it seems only to fire on a low memory condition. I would love it to fire also on an extended high CPU condition. But I have not found any resources to suggest it's possible. Does anyone know?

**Motivation:**

If you may wonder why I seek this, something nice (and simple) about that event log line is it lists what processes are using the most memory at the moment of that alert, as in:

> "Windows successfully diagnosed a low virtual memory condition. **The
>   following programs consumed the  most virtual memory**: bob.exe (9412)
>   consumed 1253019648 bytes, jane.exe (4828) consumed  430903296 bytes,
>   and bill.exe (2228) consumed 395128832 bytes." 
>   [*Emphasis is mine, and the process "names have been change to protect 
>   the innocent", as the old Dragnet TV show used to say.*]

**I would love is to get a similar list of offending processes when the system is experiencing high and prolonged excessive CPU use.**

Given the generic name of "resource exhaustion detector" (and not just "low memory detector"), I was hopeful I may find something on this, but so far my google fu is failing me.

I've also not found anything discussing **how that memory limit is set (at what size, and for what duration). That would be interesting to know as well**, if anyone may find more on configuring this detector.

(As for the secondary intent here, of knowing when CPU is high and knowing what processes are the cause, I will say that **Perfmon and its data collector sets do NOT seem the solution**. Those require that you identify the specific process(es) to watch. I am seeking with this something that fires even if I may not think to have some tool watching some particular process.)

Answer (score -1):

The answer fits to any monitoring system, like a PRTG (free up to 100 sensors) or Centreon (opensource). You add an server to monitoring, a sensor for server (mean that CPU sensor) and specify values that will trigger alerting.

The other way round is to use existing windows tools. S

1. write something in powershell
2. use Perfmon utility (it is a part of windows). Choose new performance counter alert , then specify counter and on "Alert Task" specify what to trigger. Adding an [event to eventlog](https://www.windows-commandline.com/create-event/), for instance

[image: sample in perfmon]